# What is this notation that looks like a hat above the stave?

Tags: notation, rests, drum-kits

I'm having trouble finding what this notation means:

[image: Rectangle sitting on a short line above the staff]

Comment: It looks like an actual hat

Comment: This is most likely a pause.

Comment: Could be anything - drum notation is not that standardised.

Comment: To clarify: do you know what a half rest is?

Comment: @Lazy the correct term in English is "rest."

Comment: @phoog True, had a weird moment there …

Comment: @Lazy well I live in a French-speaking place so I am accustomed to hearing and seeing "pause" for "rest" but I suppose that others might not be.

Comment: The snippet would benefit from more surrounding,  to see the preceding notes of that voice.

Comment: @phoog But with _rest_ the hat makes so much more sense. Maybe the inventor of the symbol was Mexican, and it actually depicts a sombrero and the intended term was _siesta_?

Comment: If you're reading this, please edit to explain more about your question. If you need an explanation of what the symbol means, then the present answer is good. But if you need an explanation of why it's floating above the other notes, then this should be closed as a duplicate so it doesn't attract other answers.

Comment: Feel as though you're also asking _why_ it is there... It's another voice on the same stave, that is not playing at that moment.

Answer (score 3):

It's a 2-beat, minim rest, aka half rest. We're used to seeing it within the stave.

I imagine a minim mouse sitting on the line to help me distinguish the rest from a whole (four beat) rest which hangs down below the line.

Comment: And a semibreve spider hangs under the line.  Do that with American half/whole naming!

Comment: A whole rest hangs below the line, because it is heavier.

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica Except it tends to hang from the fourth line, while the half rest likes to sit on the third. Maybe the whole rest is better able to cling to the ceiling because it's stronger?

Comment: Maybe the whole rest is afraid of falling through a whole, so it clinges to the ceiling, while the half rest says: ”Me half no fear of them wholes!“